# What is the type of new Set([1, 2, 3])

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to see what the type should be for javascripts `new Set([1, 2, 3])`, but can't find it anywhere.

for example:

```
const objNums: {[key: string]: number} = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};
const arrNums: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
const setNums /* : type??? */ = new Set([1, 2, 3]); // ????

// Example usage to explain why I need to assign a type to a variable and am asking what that type is:
function someFn(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
someFn(setNums);
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Valid javascript is valid typescript. If it works in Javascript, it works in Typescript.

Comment: @VLAZ what happens is if I try to pass `setNums` through an argument of a function, then typescript throws an error because it wants to know what type the variable is. I'm currently using `any` to get around it.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Its of type `Set<number>`

Comment: It shouldn't do that. It's perfectly valid to leave off the type annotation of a variable when it can be automatically inferred. E.g., `let x = 4` will infer that `x` is a number.

Comment: @SharedRory Awesome, thanks that worked. If you post this as an answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: [No repro on the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAcgVwLYQFwwN4G0BrAUwE8doAnASzAHMBdHMDeYygXxgF49xicARgA0MKAHcQOAEyioAC0rEBMAMwcA3AFgAUKEiwAhpUppMOAIInDpfC3RtKDHjHwiYstQ217w0GBDEUGYQLmDE4jAAykEAFG6inqoMAJQaMAD0GTAA-Hk5ukA) (there is an error but on a different line).

Comment: @VLAZ fixed the error on line 2

Comment: But still no way to reproduce the error on line 3? Do you have any sort of linter or something set up to *mandate* explicit type annotations?

Comment: @VLAZ I updated the question for you, feel free to see how it errors out.

Comment: @FiddleFreak `someFn`'s argument `arg` lacks a type annotation. That has nothing to do with Set or anything above your comment, unless you meant that you need to accept a Set of numbers and didn't know how to type `arg` as `Set<number>`. You still don't need to add `<number>` to the definition of `setNums`.

Comment: "`someFn`'s argument `arg` lacks a type annotation." This is the point I already made in my first comment/response to VLAZ. "unless you meant that you need to accept a Set of numbers and didn't know how to type arg as Set<number>" I think now you understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @SharedRory.

```
const setNums: Set<number> = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
```

If he posts his answer, I'll give him the credit.

Comment: What version of TypeScript do you use and what is your configuration? Your comments and answer seem to imply that you have to explicitly type all variables, as if automatic inferrence was disabled. Other people seem to struggle grasping your issue, because this automatic inference is considered a given since it was introduced in the early days of TS.

Comment: @ghybs version 4.4.4. we use two es-lint files(typescript and prettier) on our team. I didn't see "automatic inferrence" in either of them. Pretty much all variables in our project require variables to be strongly typed if they are being used in a function arg or reactjs jsx `.map()`. I think my question was very valid. It is simply asking what the syntax was to assign a `set` to a `type`. I wouldn't ask the question if I didn't already comb through multiple stackoverflow questions, the typescript docs, and internet blog sites.

Answer (score 0):

`new Set([1, 2, 3])` returns a value of type `Set<number>`.

**`setNums` specifically doesn't need an explicit type described on it,** because TypeScript can correctly infer the type of `setNums` during the assignment.

```
/*      GOOD */ const setNums: Set<number> = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
/* ALSO GOOD */ const setNums              = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
```

However, for an arbitrary function that would later receive `setNums`, you may need to specify the type:

```
/* UNDERSPECIFIED */ function someFn(arg             ) { /* ... */ }
/*         BETTER */ function someFn(arg: Set<number>) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: reactjs requires to sometimes use `useState<Set<number>>(new Set([1, 2, 3]));` This is why the question simply just asked what the type is, not where it should be used. The where it should be used was what the commenters started picking away at, which is why I updated the 2nd half of the question(for them). Then I saw someone changed my comment and question, so I'm just going to let it go to whatever now...